# Java NoClass Def error in Webpage

Tags: java, html

http://hobnob.fox.gy/java - Im trying to put a jar i made of some spinning cubes inside a webpage using 
    
    This example uses an applet.
    
But it comes up with a noclassdef error?

Comment: Do you have the jar in the classpath? What have you tried so far?

Comment: People usually don't want to run attached binaries to test examples, try to add some additional information (which class not found, which JVM is installed on target machine etc.)

Comment: <APPLET 
CODE="hoobcube/HoobCube.class" 
WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="800" 
ARCHIVE = "HoobCube.jar" 
> 
This example uses an applet. 
</APPLET>